# Why does latex show that {unrecognized command } when I hover over this environment , \begin{IEEEeqnarray}{rCl}

Tags: packages, texstudio, ieeetran

To use this environment I have to load this package: `\usepackage[retainorgcmds]{IEEEtrantools}`

I have the MiKTeX distribution and I didn't find this package in packages manager so I downloaded the package `.sty` file and put it in the project folder but still gives me this note

Comment: latex itself has no user interface so you can not "hover" over anything. Presumably that is your editor. If you install a package that will define commands and environments for latex but typically your editor will not "know" about them unless you also configure that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle well I'm using texstudio and in the last update it gives you the ability to hover with mouse over the commands and it will show you what it looks like in the preview . And when I hover over this environment it gives me ( unrecognized command ) .                                     Sorry, I don't understand how to configure it ?

Comment: yes as I say texstudio is just the editor, I have never used it so can not help with that. it probably doesn't really matter though, it presumably works anyway if you have installed the package so it is defined for latex.